# Учет часовых поясов посетителей

Tags: php, дата

Задача следующая,при входе в панель управления,юзеру должна показываться текущая дата и день недели но не сервера а страны в котором он находится.Как вообще реализовывается подобное? Спрашиваю так как первй раз сталкиваюсь с таким моментом.

Answer (score 2):

В первую очередь в базе данных храните все по UTC - так будет проще затем осуществлять смещение на разницу часового пояса. Затем вам следует определить часовой пояс пользователя, например, при помощи JavaScript и отправлять его на сервер

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
```

Добиться этого можно, задействовав вывод основного содержимого страницы по AJAX.
С другой стороны было бы разумно самому пользователю предоставлять выбор часового пояса. Сложности обычно начинаются, когда вам нужно агрегировать данные, например, подсчитывать количество сообщений, кликов, постов в сутки. Если пользователей не устроит окончание суток по UTC, придется пересчитывать агрегированную статистику для всех часовых поясов и выдавать пользователю соответствующий его часовому поясу вариант статистики. Если такой проблемы нет - вам повезло, вы почти не будете тратить никаких дополнительных ресурсов на поддержание часового пояса, просто корректировать дату при выводе.

Comment: Подсчета кликов и постов не будет.Данный проект своего рода тайм менеджер.

Comment: По поводу передачи часового пояса на сервер,это при каждой загрузке страницы отправлять аякс запрос?

Comment: Да, придется каждый раз отправлять, если пользователи у вас не регистрируются и не указывают часовой пояс при регистрации (такой подход, например, используется в phpBB). Если регистрации нет, то собственно, вы их и отличать друг от друга особенно-то не можете. Если регистрация предусмотрена - уже проще, можно выпытать часовой пояс на этапе регистрации, как-нибудь красиво оформить, на подобие того, как это делают инсталляторы операционных систем - карта мира с возможностью ткнуть в неё никого равнодушным не оставляет :)

Comment: Регистрация есть конечно же.Но если юзер зарегестрируется в одном часовой поясе а потом зайдет в свой аккаунт с другого? При каждом входе делать апдейт его часового пояса?

Comment: Нет, уже пускай сам следит, предусмотрите для него обновление аккаунта, если ему мешает часовой пояс - пусть обновляет его в своем личном кабинете. А может он наборот хочет общаться с друзьями из своего часового пояса и ему требуется ориентироваться по местному времени?

Answer (score 2):

Показывайте средствами JavaScript. См. [Date](https://javascript.ru/Date)

Чтобы обрабатывать средствами PHP локальные для пользователя дату/время, потребуется определить его временную зону. Тут я вижу три пути. Два первых указаны в соседнем ответе. Дополнительно можно запросить [данные геолокации](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) и таким образом узнать или подтвердить временную зону (но это сложный путь).

В настоящее время задача автоопределения временной зоны клиента не решаема без JavaScript.

Comment: А средствами Php,допустим localtime?

Comment: Для этого в PHP потребуется передать временную зону