# date() почему выводит не локальное время?

Tags: php

Нашёл скрипт вывода даты на русском языке , но она выводит время не с моего компа , где ошибка ?

```
function rusdate($d, $format = 'j %MONTH% Y', $offset = 0)
{
    $montharr = array(
      'января', 'февраля', 'марта', 'апреля', 'мая', 'июня',
      'июля', 'августа', 'сентября', 'октября', 'ноября', 'декабря');
    $dayarr = array(
       'понедельник', 'вторник', 'среда', 'четверг',
      'пятница', 'суббота', 'воскресенье');

    $d += 3600 * $offset;

    $sarr = array('/%MONTH%/i', '/%DAYWEEK%/i');
    $rarr = array( $montharr[date("m", $d) - 1], $dayarr[date("N", $d) - 1] );

    $format = preg_replace($sarr, $rarr, $format); 
    return date($format, $d);
}
```

Вызов скрипта

```
<?php echo rusdate( time(), '%DAYWEEK%, j %MONTH% Y, G:i' ); ?>
```

а выводит время на час больше :

```
воскресенье, 15 мая 2016, 10:38
```

а у меня :

```
воскресенье, 15 мая 2016, 9:38
```

Comment: `Да, и еще. У функции есть необязательный третий параметр — сдвиг времени. Можно указать кол-во часов, на которые необходимо сдвинуть время относительно часового пояса на сервере.`

Comment: это как делается ?

Comment: Что значит как? Я вам привел часть описание, которое автор давал на своей странице. Вы вызываете функцию только с двумя параметрами, а надо вызывать с тремя, указав в третьем разницу между часовым поясом сервера и вашим, наверное.

Comment: от того что я изменил offset на -1 , это ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если не сложно посмотрите в php.ini или через функцию `phpinfo()` ваш часовой пояс, установленный в директиве `date.timezone`

```
date.timezone = 'Europe/Moscow'
```

Он соответствует часовому поясу, где вы находитесь? У меня ваш скрипт отработал без ошибок.

Comment: да точно - европа/москва была , спасибо , а на реальном сервере как боротся с этим ?

Comment: @LenovoID, можно воспользоваться функцией date_default_timezone_set()

Comment: да я то уже читал эту функцию, но как на реальном сервере для пользователя N из страны Y вычислять ?

Comment: @LenovoID, возможно вас заинтересует следующий ответ http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/502942

Comment: тогда это получается "танцы с бубном" ?

Comment: Автоматических средств нет - придется запрограммировать ситуацию, но я бы не назвал ситуацию из рук вон выходящей.

Comment: если нету стандартной функции значит "танцы ... "

Comment: Ее не может быть, так как часовой пояс у каждого клиента разный и вы можете узнать ее только в браузере, на сервере вы можете получить эту информацию, только отправив её запросом из браузера. К сожалению, тут ничего поделать нельзя, клиентский и серверный код разнесены в пространстве и разделены по времени выполнения.

Comment: cheops спасибо , буду курить это , жаль инфы на эту тему очень мало а тот кто знает ни делится  , но ладно дойду сам , буду смотреть в сторону node